# java loop displaying an image in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Hello i'm trying to make an image fill the screen. The image is 20x20 pixels. i don't really know how to explain it. I think the code might explain it better thank you for your help. and the screen is 800x600 pixels. I have looked for a few days and found nothing.i want it to fill the whole screen with this image i just cant get it and to fill it i need it to repeat and not just use one square.

```
        private int GLW = 0;
        private int GLH = 0;
        private int add = 20;
        private int redo1 = 0;

        while(redo1 < 24000){
        int redo = 0;
        if(redo < 1){

            //image here
            java.net.URL imageURL = getClass().getResource("grass.png");
            img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageURL));
            JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
            pan1.add(img);
            add(img, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            img.setVisible(true);
            img.setBounds(GLH,GLW,20 ,20 );

            GLW = GLW + add;
            GLH = GLH + add;

        }
        GLW=GLW+20;
    }
```

Comment: No, actually, the code doesn't explain much. What do you want it to do, and what does it do that you don't like? Edit your question, and I suggest adding the `java` tag while you're at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'm trying to make an image fill the screen. The image is 20x20 pixels

Then you need to tile the image.

Check out [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which allows you to add an image to a panel and support tiling. The basic code would be:

```
BackgroundPanel panel = new BackgroundPanel(image, BackgroundPanel.TILED);
frame.add( panel );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom class that extends JPanel, then overwrite the paintComponent method.
This works for me:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

    private Image backgroundImage;

    public BackgroundPanel(String fileName) {
        backgroundImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y += backgroundImage.getHeight(null)) {
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x += backgroundImage.getWidth(null)) {
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage,x,y,null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add this panel to your frame instead of a regular JPanel:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Background Image Example");
                String imageUrl = "path/to/image.extension";

                BackgroundPanel panel = new BackgroundPanel(imageUrl);
                //add any other elements and customize panel
                frame.add(panel);
                //add any other elements and customize jframe

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```